# Excel: Counting the number of text strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column in a spreadsheet which lists the status of particular rows - the statuses are text strings like "accepted" "rejected" and so on.

Is there any formula I can use to count the number of times each status occurs in a given column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNTIF`.

Assuming you want to count "Accepted" in cells A1:A30:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A30, "=Accepted")`

Comment: Thank you very much I'm having some trouble doing this cross workbook, for some reason ='Backlog'!COUNTIF(J1:J3000, "=Accepted") does not seem to work

Comment: and then I thought about it a bit more and realised that =COUNTIF('Backlog'!J1:J3000, "=Accepted") was what I was looking for!

Comment: Great!  Let me know if you have more trouble with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pivot table.  Put the status field in the row area and some other field in the data area.  If necessary, change the summary function to 'Count Of' for the data field.  That will give you a count for each status (and blanks).

Comment: Thank you, if I could have accepted both answers I would have